# how to check null in javaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to check null and empty id in JavaScript function,but if syntax isn't work ?

```
var id = "<%=Request["Id"]%>";
 if (id !== "")
 if (id !== null)
{var id = "<%=new Guid(Request["ID"].ToString())%>";
 window.location = "/Controller/Action.aspx?Id=" + id; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read into binary logic:

```
var id = "<%=Request["Id"]%>";
if (id !== "" && id != null)  {
    var id = "<%=new Guid(Request["ID"].ToString())%>";
    window.location = "/Controller/Action.aspx?Id=" + id;
}
```

Then again, `var id = "<%=Request["Id"]%>";` will never be null, only empty string, so perhaps you can drop that check altogether.

Comment: if (id !== "" && id != null)

Comment: Are you sure? It's valid JavaScript so perhaps it's ASP doing something?

Comment: I search about && syntax  in java script  and concluded that separated if syntax

Comment: Try with a regular html page, separate ifs may work with the braces in the right places but binary logic is far easier to read.

Comment: I try it but if condition passed. how can i see value of id ? with alert syntax?

Comment: Do you see it currently? Look into `console.log()` or step debugging in your favourite browser's web developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript,

If you are trying to test for not-null (any value that is not explicitly NULL) this should work for you:

```
if( myVar !== null ) { 
    // your code
}
```

If you are only interested to test for not-empty (null value, zero number, empty string etc..) then try:

```
if( !myVar ) { 
    // your code
}
```

If you want to test for if a variable is defined at all (**which I believe is what you are trying to achieve**) then you can do it like:

```
if( typeof myVar !== 'undefined' ) { 
    // your code
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you.